# Postgres 9.3 changes the standard_conforming_strings value

Tags: postgresql, schema, pg-dump

I'm migrating a legacy application's database from Postgres 8.1 to Postgres 9.3

In order to avoid compatibility issues, I'd like to keep the `standard_conforming_strings` parameter to it's default value in 8.1: `off`.

So, I create the databases using following in the schema:

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
```

But a pg_dump of the database reveals that Postgres has changed the value to `on`.

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

How exactly did you set [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS)?

If you did that in your session, it only applies to that session. For a permanent setting change your `postgresql.conf` and reload.

Also, a `pg_dump` does not reveal anything. The setting in the dump only applies to the dump. To see the current setting of your database, run:

```
SHOW standard_conforming_strings;
```

Or get more details from [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'standard_conforming_strings';
```

Generally, it's a ***very bad idea*** to try and keep `standard_conforming_strings` off. This was [changed with Postgres 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/release-9-1.html#AEN110428) for a good reason. It's going to bite you sooner or later. Update to the current (superior) standard.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the alter command.

```
  ALTER USER your_login_name SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS TO OFF;
```

`ALTER DATABASE` can also be used here, but as standard conforming strings are simpler to use it's probably best to keep the old-style restricted to legacy users.

a better approach is to use `e` to prefix escaped strings if you ever need them.