# Postgresql: ILIKE query with % as search term

Tags: postgresql, query, like

I have a JDBC query that performs an ILIKE operation.

```
select project_name from project_table where project_name ILIKE '%test%';
```

The above returns all the results matching (wildcarded) the term `test`.

However, when the project_name is `%project_name` and the user searches for just `%`, the query returns all the rows instead of just the matching row.

Essentially the query becomes `select project_name from project_table where project_name ILIKE '%%%';`

I understand the concept of wildcarding in postgresql, but is there a way to just limit the result matching the `%`?

Comment: Please remember to *always* disclose the Postgres version in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the special meaning with a backslash (`\`):

```
WHERE project_name ILIKE '%\%project_name';
```

Matches any string that ends with '%project_name'.
The first `%` serves as wildcard, the second, escaped `\%` matches a literal '%'.

Or use the function I provided here (along with detailed explanation) :

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630/939860)

If `'%\%%'` works like `'%%%'` for you then - like jjanes hinted - you are probably running with the outdated setting [**`standard_conforming_strings = off`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS), where `\` is interpreted away as escape character.
The default is `on` since Postgres 9.1. **(!)**

**Solution:** Double up `\` and prepend the string with `E`, like: `E'%\\%%'`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=26435792e41f6430a0524cd0aebda754)*

Or, ***much rather***, upgrade to a current version of Postgres with proper settings. See:

- [Postgres 9.3 changes the standard_conforming_strings value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71681/postgres-9-3-changes-the-standard-conforming-strings-value/71683#71683)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)

Comment: `ILIKE '%\%project_name';` works when the search-term is `%project_name`. However, when the search-term is just `%`, I still get back all the results (`WHERE project_name ILIKE '%\%%';`) instead of just one row -- `%project_name`.

Comment: @Pavan: That shouldn't be (unless all project names contain a literal `%`). *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f20b364711ab877e9af56364a68918e1)*. Maybe some component of your food-chain escapes the `\\`? [Log statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) and check your database log what Postgres actually receives if you are unsure.

Comment: Executing the query directly in psql:

`select project_name from project_table WHERE project_name ILIKE '%\%%';
 project_name 
--------------
 %test_name
 project-1
 project-1
(3 rows)`

Comment: @Pavan - if you wish to demonstrate SQL functionality, far better to use db<>fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) and put the link here - comments don't format very well and your message from the above isn't very clear - a fiddle would rectify that!

Comment: @Pavan  Maybe you have standard_conforming_strings = off.

Comment: @jjanes: I think you nailed it. I added pointers.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks! Backslash worked after setting the property to "on". Thank you